# Algorithm to get a list of center points whose radius covers every point within an area

Tags: algorithm, lua

I have a plane with a bunch of points (x, y coordinates) scattered all over, and I need to encircle each of them within as few circles of the same radius as possible. Something like this:
[image]

To get a result of a list of center points for the circles that will enclose each of those points, like this:
[image]

So the data would be a list of points and the fixed radius for the circles to enclose them, and the result would be a list of as few center points as possible to enclose each.
I'm currently working in Lua, so if there's a library that has functions to achieve this, or if someone knows an algorithm or can point me in the right direction mathematically, that'd be great!

Comment: Do you know vronoi-diagram datastructure?

Answer (score 1):

Create an [adjacency matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) for the graph of nodes (nodes are connected only if they are close enough), and you can easily see which is the best way to group them.

Just group them starting from the node (vertex) that has the [highest degree](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexDegree.html).

I'll add a code when I'm at a computer.